# How do I add an onclick event to the OK button of the Javascript confirm box?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

I am working with a .Net 1.1 web application.  There is a Save button that, when clicked, will pop up the Javascript confirm box.  Once the user clicks OK a long running process is kicked off.  We would like to show a busy indicator when the user clicks the OK button of the confirm dialog.  Can this be done?

Comment: BYW - this is on the client, so it has nothing to do with .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you would like to save?")){
    alert("Loading") //Replace with what you want to do  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button on an `alert()` dialog is not scriptable. You need to find where in the code the `alert()` is called and patch in to the code just after this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pretty simple. A `confirm('Text')` returns true or false after the user  makes their selection. All you need to do is on true show a busy indication.

Here is what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/C6ZZf/

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {
    var shouldSave = confirm('Make your choice');

    if(shouldSave) {
        alert('Do saving');
    }
    else {   
        alert('Not saving'); 
    }
});
```